# Нужен ли тут конструктор копирования

Tags: c++, ооп, конструктор, конструктор-копирования

Вообщем есть такое задание.

Создать класс Студент с полями
фамилия,
количество оценок,
оценки (динамический массив оценок).
  определить методы
конструктор (ы)
конструктор копирования
деструктор
метод вывода информации о студенте.
Определить класс Преподаватель (фамилия, предмет) с методом выставления оценки некотором студенту за определенную лабораторную работу. Продемонстрировать взаимодействие классов.

Я не могу понять зачем тут может понадобится конструктор копирования?Уже второе подобное задание.Я уже сколько думал, но в моем решении он только мешает.Может кто подсказать?

Answer (score 0):

> Оценки (динамический массив оценок)

Значит, вы выделяете память динамически, а в классе храните на нее указатель. Если вы не создаете копирующий конструктор - сгенерированный компилятором будет просто копировать этот указатель. И если вы не устраиваете утечку памяти, а освобождаете память в деструкторе - то в результате вы ее освободите два раза...

Вам надо неприятностей? Их есть у двойного освобождения памяти.

Та же ерунда будет и если вы ре реализуете оператор присваивания.

Можно **запретить** копирование и присваивание вообще - но это, скажем так, **очень резко** ограничит применимость вашего класса...

Comment: Ну и в каком месте его потом нужно будет  вызывать?

Comment: А вы интереса ради напишите заглушку - просто копирующий конструктор и копирующее присваивание пусть выводят строку и больше ничего не делают. И в тот момент, когда ваша программа вдруг выведет это сообщение о вызове - посмотрите сами :) Слушайте, кстати! а деструктор вам зачем? В каком месте вы его потом вызываете? Может, и его - нафиг?... Впрочем, можете обойтись и без конструктора копирования. Потом просто будете здесь же спрашивать, почему ваша программа слетает...

Comment: А что не так с двойным освобождением? Имеется ввиду, что между освобождениями кто-то может записать свои данные по этому адресу?

Comment: @Grundy Гм. `int * i = new int; delete i; delete i;` - я имел в виду, что если не сделать копирующий конструктор, то можно нарваться на эту вот ситуацию...

Comment: Я читал что конструктор копированию нужен в 3 случаях: 1)Передача в функцию 2)возврат из функции 3)и копирование одного объекта в другой. Зачем он мне тут если я из вышеперечисленного ничего не делаю и где его тулить, я понять не могу

Comment: Я же написал - не делайте. Извините, что ввел вас в заблуждение. Эти преподы - они вообще всякую фигню задают, которая потом никому и никогда не нужна. Еще раз извините. Кстати, конечно же, вы организуете взаимодействие классов без вызовов методов, например - смешно даже подумать об ином решении :)

Comment: @Harry, а :-) не знал что это UB :) я бы подумал, что второй раз просто ничего не произойдет

Comment: можете и не писать КК ОП и Д, если используете умный указатель

Answer (score 0):

Что случится, если для класса, имеющего указатель или ссыльку, не определить 
конструктор копирования, оператор присваивания и деструктор?.. Пример:

```
class Student {
    static int k;
    unsigned* grade;
    //...
public:
    Student() : grade(new unsigned[20]) { ++k; cout << "Constructor" << k <<'\n';}
    ~Student() {   cout << "Destructor\n"; }
};
int Student::k = 0;
int main()
{       
    Student  s;     // вызывается конструктор (создается массив 1 в динамической области
    Student s2 = s; // копируется указатель ( оба указателья указывают на массив) 1
    Student s3;     // вызывается конструктор (создается массив 2 в динамической области
    s3 = s;         // копируется указатель, поэтому указатель s3 указывает на 1
    // получается что на массив созданный вызовом конструктора s3 ничего не указывет
    // и его нельзя уничтожить.
    // С другой стороны массив 1 уничтожается 3 раза
    return 0;
}
```

Это приведет к массу неприятносей

Comment: Так мне же  там по идее нечего копировать или присваивать.Нафига он нужен?

Comment: Один "студент" и "учитель", там нечего копировать

Comment: Если вам нечего копировать и присваивать, то объявите явно конструктор копирования и присваивания удаленными. Это делается парой строк. Но если вы все-таки попробуете где-то в коде клонировать студента - то вам компилятор сообщит об ошибке. И тогда "мешающие" методы вам придется реализовать согласно букварю

Comment: Если вы это пишете, чтоб создать один пассивный обьект, и  после этого не использовать класс или созданный обьект, тогда не пишите класс вообше.  Если вы задали вопрос с целью  упорно утверждать, что не нужно определять ничего, тогда я не понимаю  зачем вы вообше задаете вопрос... На этом закончим